# Обновление содержимого одного из табов

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Вешаю на один из элементов событие `change(event)`. По приходу этого события хочу обновить содержимое таба. Для создания табов использую JQuery. Если в обработчике просто написать

```
$(containerId).tabs("select", index);
```

то ничего не происходит. Как правильно обновлять данные в табе?

Еще, в обработчике `select`'а у меня формируется верный URL табы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для обновления таба надо делать так:

```
$(containerId).tabs("load", index);
```

Думаю тут вся загвоздка в функционал обработчика события `select`. Вынесите все в отдельную ф-ю. Перед вызовом `load` вызвайте обработчик селекта.